# Deploy Django app on a server is giving me 404 with static files

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy a Djagon app to a production server, but is not working, even if I seet `DEBUG`variable to `True`.

For what I understand, Heroku is collecting the static files, so should work.

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        119 static files copied to '/tmp/build_80f75579ac26656d613f32473cdc0923/staticfiles', 12 unmodified.
```

**production.py**

```
from wall_web_interface.settings.common import *

DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

settings = dynaconf.DjangoDynaconf(__name__)
```

**common.py**

```
"""
Django settings for wall_web_interface project.

Generated by 'Django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dynaconf

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "dkjdkjdkjdkdjkdjdi8383383j"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'sass_processor',
    'images.apps.ImagesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wall_web_interface.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Django Sass
SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wall_web_interface.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-cl'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Santiago'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

I have been searching for hours, but I always get the same result, 404 in every static file. In my understanding, I'm doing everything right.

My folders are in this order:

> my_project
>
> - image_proc
> - - static
> - static
> - templates
> - image_proc_web
> - - settings

Comment: You need to create a staticfiles folder. [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds).